# Filter list by selected option in vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Im trying out vue.js and cannot really figure out how i can filter a rendered list of items by simply select an option in a  box.

Each list item has a pric property. eg. $200, $500, $600 etc.

My select box options each has a price range. eg 0 - $250, $250 - $500, $500 - $750.

When i for example choose $200 - $500 in the select box i only want the items in the list which has a price somewhere in between that range to be visible.

html:

```
<select>
    <option>
        Price 0 - 250
    </option>
    <option>
        Price 250 - 500
    </option>
    <option>
        Price 500 - 750
    </option>
    <option>
        Price 750 - 1000
    </option>
</select>
```

template:

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items">
    {{ item.price }} // some price in $. eg. $ 340. different for each 
item
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i first misunderstood the question I've updated the original answer.
Anyway, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/3427/) is a jsfiddle that does what i believe you are trying to do.

```
 Vue.filter('currency', function (value) {
    return '€ ' + parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
});

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        items: [5,20],
        limits: [{min: 1, max: 10}, {min:11, max: 25}, {min:26, max: 50}],
        option: 0
    },
    computed: {
        selectedList () {
        var ul = [];
        for(i =0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            if (this.items[i] > this.limits[this.option].min && this.items[i] < this.limits[this.option].max) {
            ul.push(this.items[i])
          }
        }
        return ul;
      }
    }
})
```

I've placed your min/max values in an array so we can loop through these with our select element. Than we create a computed array, this array returns all values between the selected min/max.

I've also added a filter to add the currency symbol.

Comment: sounds good. but how do i apply that to work with a select box?

Comment: hmm, not really. as it is now the data in my select is static strings, as you see in my code. whatever you choose in the select, all items in my <li> between those two numbers in my select should be visible <li>'s.

Comment: Tanks! first fiddle is just what i need.

Comment: Last question! my application loading the data from a static json file, which make it unaccessible for the computed. How would you solve that?

Comment: Im now trying with v-on:change="filterFunc" instead, but then the if statements not working.